# CANNOT connect to SQL Server from Django on Heroku

Tags: python, sql-server, django, heroku, django-pyodbc-azure

My website will just load an existing table (brand) from SQL server and display to index page. I'm able to run the website on my machine without any problem, but it seems like the table doesn't exist when I deploy the project to Heroku.

(The deploy is working normally if the website doesn't connect to the SQL Server.)

#### These are my settings:

**runtime.txt**

```
python-3.7.0
```

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn project_heroku.wsgi --log-file -
```

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': DB_DEFAULT_NAME,
        'USER': DB_USER,
        'PASSWORD': DB_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': DB_HOST,
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
            'unicode_results': True,    
        }
    }
}
```

**models.py**

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'brand'
```

**views.py**

```
from .models import Brand

def index(request):
    brand = list(Brand.objects.all().values())
    context = {
        'brand': brand
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

I added 2 build packs on Heroku

1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt
2. heroku/python

**In my Aptfile**

```
unixodbc
unixodbc-dev
python-pyodbc
libsqliteodbc
```

**In my requirements.txt**

```
django
pyodbc
gunicorn
django-heroku
django-pyodbc-azure
```

The package has been built successfully, but the website give this error

```
ProgrammingError at /
relation "brand" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "brand"."id", "brand"."name" FROM "brand"
```

[image: ERROR SCREENSHOT]

Please help! Thanks!!

============================

#### Update:

I found that Heroku automatically create and attach postgresql which I didn't want. Therefore, I deleted the postgresql and the error is changed to Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found. :( I guess that I have to do something with DATABASE_URL config.

Comment: Did you do `heroku run manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Yes I did (both migrate and makemigrations). In the log, it said that all user login tables have been created (I didn't use them, and they were already exist). The problem is still there

Comment: Are you using difference database on production? Are you sure table exists in database?

Comment: Yes, I run exactly the same code on my machine, and it works fine.

Comment: OK, I found that Heroku automatically create and attach postgresql which I didn't want. Therefore, I deleted the postgresql and the error is changed to Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found. :( I guess that I have to do something with DATABASE_URL config.